Как вставить пробел в строке после заданной подстроки
На вход программе подается две строки S и Sub, каждая в отдельной строке.  Строка Sub гарантированно содержится в строке S.
Вставить после указанной строки Sub в строке S один пробел.
Результат вывести на консоль.
string S = Console.ReadLine();
string Sub = Console.ReadLine();
 
var newS = S.IndexOf(Sub, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(S.Insert(newS, " "));

Не могу понять, что надо добавить, чтобы сделать без цикла, подскажите пожалуйста.

Нужно использовать метод Substring и добавить к позиции newS длину подстроки, после которой нужно выполнить вставку.
Дополнение: Также можно использовать метод Insert с правильно рассчитанной позицией вставки.
string S = Console.ReadLine(); 
string Sub = Console.ReadLine();

var newS = S.IndexOf(Sub, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + Sub.Length;

Console.WriteLine(S.Substring(0, newS) + " " + S.Substring(newS));
// вариант с Insert
Console.WriteLine(S.Insert(newS, " "));


Спасибо огромное!!!, а вот,как бы чтобы Insert там присутствовал если не сложно) Пытался сдвинуть пробел, но ничего не подходит.Только учу строки.

Да, с Insert тоже можно, дополнил ответ.  Фактически, в первоначальном коде нужно было всего лишь добавить длину строки Sub к позиции.

спасибо, после вашего кода понял как делать с Insert

всё с кодом замечательно!

Nowhere Man я делал S.Insert(newS + newS.Length, " ") и у меня ошибка выскакивала

У newS нет метода Length, это число )

спасибо за подсказку,уже понял свою ошибку))
